# I want modify this code as when a user gives right name but wrong password code must run from enter password not from enter username again

Tags: python, while-loop, passwords, user-input, continue

```
while True:
    print("who is this?")
    name=input()
    if name!='shubh':
        continue
    print("hi its you shubh. type your password")  
    password=input()
    if password!="shubh": 
        print("try again. wrong password")
    elif password=="shubh":
        break
print("access granted")
```

**when the user gives correct id but wrong password code must run from password input and not from start**

Comment: then you probably will require two loops.  1 for username,  2) for the password.

Answer (score 1):

You could try as @ewong suggested

```
while True:
    print("who is this?")
    name=input()
    if name=='shubh':
        break
    print("Please try again")
while True:
    print("hi its you shubh. type your password")
    password=input()
    if password!="shubh":
        print("try again. wrong password")
    elif password=="shubh":
        break
print("access granted")
```